# How webpack know about project specific dependency in workspace when create chunk for the particular app or lib

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl

In the latest angular-cli version, we create Workspace and than in app(s) folder we can create apps and library etc. So all apps will be pointing to the same node_modules folder.

So my question is that how or what basis webpack come to know that, which dependency is related to particular app at the build time, if there are more than one app in workspace.

It can be done based on import statement in the app but I want to be sure about it.

Please do let me know if you need details or steps or my question is not clear.

Comment: Sandeep Saroha did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @MarlonPatrick, Not yet. I got busy with some other stuff and didn't research around this.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the file packages file  .angular-cli.json or  angular.json